# change thefootnote command with bigfoot

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

I would like to have two series of footnotes, and to mark the difference among them with one having numbers like "1" and the other with "(1)".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
%% \renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{(\arabic{footnoteB})}
\newcommand{\FNone}[1]{\footnoteA{#1}}
\newcommand{\FNtwo}[1]{\footnoteB{#1}}

\begin{document}

Lalala\FNone{One.} Lalala\FNone{One.} Lalala\FNone{One.}

Lalala\FNtwo{Two.} Lalala\FNtwo{Two.} Lalala\FNtwo{Two.}
\end{document}
```

Without changing anything, small footnotes share the same line:

[image]

But if I uncomment the line above, trying to add the parentheses, I lose something, and the notes don’t stack anymore:

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: What about `\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{(\roman{footnoteB})}` for example?

Comment: I might have thousands of notes :'( so the roman numbers would get absurd

Comment: Just thought the problem might be the character height, because ```\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{·\arabic{footnoteB}·}``` works, perhaps with smaller parentheses...

Comment: yep, this kind of works, but I have no idea why: ```\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{{\tiny (}\arabic{footnoteB}{\tiny )}}```

Comment: Good piece of news :) I'll elaborate then in an answer.

Comment: It works fine for me (uncommented).  I tried it with XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and PDFLaTeX (without fontspec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bigfoot`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) documentation is very terse, but it's said that it's “interface is identical to that of [`manyfoot`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot); users should seek information from that package's documentation.” According to the documentation of that later, the command `\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{X}` does :

- `\newfootnote{X}` to create the footnote level
- `\newcounter{footnoteX}` for the associated counter
- `\newcommand{\footnoteX}` to create the insertion command

So, my idea was to rebuild the counter to sweet your needs: `\renewcommand{\thefootnoteX}{(\arabic{footnoteX})}`

A better way may be to do the full thing yourself

```latex
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\newcounter{footnoteB}
\newcommand{\footnoteB}{%
  \stepcounter{footnoteB}%
  \Footnotemark(\thefootnoteB) \FootnotetextB{}%
}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\arabic{footnoteB}}
```

I find it better because the counter may be used at some other location without need of the parens.

One may want to use the new hook, but I don't see how to achieve it in this case.

```latex
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\SetFootnoteHook{(}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[arabic]
```